# "npm start" shows "Unhandled promise rejection" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start, react-scripts

I am new to NodeJS and NPM.

When I run `npm start` within a NodeJS project, the following errors occurred:

```
Starting the development server...

(node:9417) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3
```

What does this error mean?
How should debug this problem?

```
$ grep start package.json 
    "start": "react-scripts start",

$ npm -v
3.10.10
$ node -v
v6.10.1

$ npm ls react-scripts
reference-apps@2.3.1 /home/li/sample
└── react-scripts@0.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code like below

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    reject(0)
}).then()
```

when you run the code above, you will get “Unhandled promise rejection”.

with Promise/A+ standard [#point-21](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-21). A promise must provide a then method to access its current or eventual value or reason.

you'd better write code as below

```
promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
```

the other way to avoid the issue, you can listen the `unhandledRejection` event with process

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to know where this error is from? There are many `reject()` in the code. I am not sure which one is causing the error.